# Discord.py - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, discord.py, typeerror

I have some bugs in below code:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def leaderboard(self, ctx):
        with open('Level.json','r', encoding='utf8') as jfile:
            jdata = json.load(jfile)

        leaderboard = []
        total = []
        
        x = ctx.guild.member_count

        for user in list(jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)]):
            level = jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user)]['level']
            print(jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)])
            print(jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user)]['level'])
            xp = jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user)]['xp']
            final_level = level * 100 
            final = xp + final_level

            if leaderboard == []:
                leaderboard.append(str(user))
            
            else:
                leaderboard.append("," + str({user}))
            
            if total == []:
                total.append(str(final))

            else: 
                total.append("," + str({final}))
            

        final_total = sorted(total,reverse=False)
        

        embed=discord.Embed(title=f'Leaderboard', color=0xf1c40f)
        
        index = 1
        for amt in final_total:
            id_ = leaderboard[amt]
            member = self.bot.get_user(id_)

            level_show = jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            xp_show = jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['xp']
                
            embed.add_field(name=f'Rank {index}', value = f'{member.mention} | Level {level_show} | Experiences {xp_show}', inline=False)
            
            
            if index == x:
                break
            else:
                index += 1
            
        embed.set_footer(text="Powered by OWCA")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

Output:

```
{'872086460973604914': {'xp': 2, 'level': 2, 'rank': 'Below 10'}}
2
An exception has occurred while executing command `leaderboard`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1353, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 209, in invoke
    return await self.func(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cmds/Level.py", line 150, in leaderboard
    id_ = leaderboard[amt]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Json POV:

```
{
    "<ctx.guild.id here>": {
        "<user.id here>": {
            "xp": 2,
            "level": 2,
            "rank": "Below 10"
        }
    }
}
```

Also I am building leaderboard with slash command and json to write this stuff.

I have read other question with this error but after reading them, I still cannot know where is the error here. If you need more code tell me please. I imported json and made sure the 'Level.json' is on my folder.

**Edited**
Added print ctx.guild and level

Comment: Please do not mind the "rank" in json pov. I though maybe it will be useful in the future :)

Comment: Have you tried printing `jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user)]`?

Comment: when something wrong happen with a variable : **print** so `print(jdata)` then `print(jdata[str(ctx.guild.id)])` then with user level, and you'll find the issue

Comment: also why reading the file in the loop, and not ONCE before ?

Comment: Okay, I edited. the output level is correct as jdata

Comment: Are you sure that the error is there? Your traceback says `File "/home/container/cmds/Level.py", line 150, in leaderboard id_ = leaderboard[amt]`

Comment: Oh, it is my problem but it was a error in past. I guess I fixed it. Now full command is provided